# PHP Wrong parameter count for mysql_query() - Possible Syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql

I've been battling with this for a while, I'm not familiar with PHP syntax, here's my code:

```
    $eventArray = array($this->ReturnLastRecordId() + 1, $managerid, $title, $description, $category, $address, $location, $startdate, $starttime, $enddate, $endtime, $price, $endofticketdate, $totalseats,  $totalseats);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO event (eventid, managerid, title, description, category, address, location, startdate, starttime, enddate, endtime, price, endofticketdate, totalseats, totalseats)";
    $data->StoreData($eventArray, $sql);
```

In the function:

```
public function StoreData($dataArray, $sqlquery)
    {

        include 'config.php';

        $i = count($dataArray);
        echo $i;
        switch ($i) {
            case 15:
            mysql_query($sqlquery . "VALUES (" . '$arraydata[0]' ,   '$arraydata[1]',  '$arraydata[2]',  '$arraydata[3]', '$arraydata[4]', '$arraydata[5]', '$arraydata[6]', '$arraydata[7]', '$arraydata[8]', '$arraydata[9]',  '$arraydata[10]', '$arraydata[11]', '$arraydata[12]',  '$arraydata[13]',  '$arraydata[14]' . ")", $con) or die (mysql_error());
            mysql_close($con);
                break;

        }
    }
```

Obviously I've checked the number of parameters multiple times, including the database, but still the parameter count get thrown :(.

Comment: Commas should be inside the strings. You can see from the highlighting that they are in the wrong place.

Comment: Why are there 2x `totalseats` columns? The other serious issue is that `eventid` is not an auto-incrementing field. Incrementing `eventid` the way you are doing it is inviting a race condition where two queries running at the same time could overlap and write the wrong `eventid`.

Comment: Are prepared statements really that much trouble, that no one ever wants to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not concatenating the SQL string. Your code passes multiple separate PHP function parameters.

The most lazy fix would be:

```
 $values = implode("','", $arraydata);

 mysql_query("$sqlquery VALUES ('$values')");
```

I would advise that you enclose the whole single string that mysql_query expects in double quotes, and then use string interpolation within. Avoid manual `.` concatenation.

Comment: This is obviously the cleanest solution and I'd like to suggest also to use an escaping function such as `mysql_real_escape_string()` to protect the query parameters. +1 for you

Comment: With `$arraydata = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $arraydata);` it's particularly easy here, if the data wasn't already escaped before. (Remember: magic_quotes were safe anno PHP3 for single byte charset databases only.)

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution, will dramatically decrease my code :)

Answer (score 0):

Your concatenation of the sql query is wrong. The commas in your solution are outside of the string, thus interpreted by php as additional paramaters.

It should be something like this:

```
    mysql_query($sqlquery . " VALUES ('$arraydata[0]' ,   '$arraydata[1]', )
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You used the concatenation operand `.` when building your SQL query where you shouldn't have.
Give a try with the following:

```
public function StoreData($dataArray, $sqlquery) {

    include 'config.php';

    $i = count($dataArray);
    echo $i;
    switch ($i) {
        case 15:
            mysql_query($sqlquery . " VALUES ('{$arraydata[0]}', '{$arraydata[1]}', '{$arraydata[2]}', '{$arraydata[3]}', '{$arraydata[4]}', '{$arraydata[5]}', '{$arraydata[6]}', '{$arraydata[7]}', '{$arraydata[8]}', '{$arraydata[9]}', '{$arraydata[10]}', '{$arraydata[11]}', '{$arraydata[12]}', '{$arraydata[13]}', '{$arraydata[14]}')", $con) or die (mysql_error());
            mysql_close($con);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this modification of your code:

```
    $eventArray = array(($this->ReturnLastRecordId() + 1), $managerid, $title, $description, $category, $address, $location, $startdate, $starttime, $enddate, $endtime, $price, $endofticketdate, $totalseats,  $totalseats);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO event (eventid, managerid, title, description, category, address, location, startdate, starttime, enddate, endtime, price, endofticketdate, totalseats, totalseats)";
    $data->StoreData($eventArray, $sql);

public function StoreData($dataArray, $sqlquery)
    {

        include 'config.php';

        $i = count($dataArray);
        echo $i;
        switch ($i) {
            case 15:
            mysql_query($sqlquery . " VALUES (" . '$arraydata[0]' ,   '$arraydata[1]',  '$arraydata[2]',  '$arraydata[3]', '$arraydata[4]', '$arraydata[5]', '$arraydata[6]', '$arraydata[7]', '$arraydata[8]', '$arraydata[9]',  '$arraydata[10]', '$arraydata[11]', '$arraydata[12]',  '$arraydata[13]',  '$arraydata[14]' . ")", $con) or die (mysql_error());
            mysql_close($con);
                break;

        }
    }
```